# How to type mathematical accent in MS office suite?

Tags: microsoft-office

For example if I want to insert $\bar{x}$, it is simply typing \bar{x} in LaTeX.

In Onenote and other MS office products, you first type Alt+= to enter the math environment, and after you type \bar, what is the next keystroke I'm suppose to press so that I can type $x$ under the bar?

I have tried many combination, including {, (, space, tab. None of them work, they just skip the part under the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps:

**1.** Press **Alt+=**

**2.** Type **x\bar**

**3.** Then press **space bar** two times